Contain text inside marker for expo react native
I am using Expo version 49 under React Native, with react-google-maps version 9.4.5 to create markers.
I have this template:
<Marker
  coordinate={{
    latitude: latitude,
    longitude: longitude,
  }}
  image={Images.marker.hotel_large}
  tracksViewChanges={false}
  centerOffset={{ x: 0, y: -10 }}
  {...rest}
>
  <View style={styles.text}>
    <BaseText style={{ color: '#fff' }}>{label}</BaseText>
  </View>
  <Callout style={[styles.plainView, { width: scale(270) }]}>{children}</Callout>
</Marker>

and create a style in JavaScript like so:
export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  plainView: {
    width: scale(200),
  },
  priceSection: {
    color: Color.primary,
  },
  text: {
    color: '#FFF',
    textAlign: 'center',
    width: 48,
    paddingTop: 22,
    paddingLeft: 18,
  },
});

In my app, if the font size is increased (through accessibility), the text goes outside the marker:

How can I fix this issue?

You have a lot of padding in your text style. At the same time, you are also setting the width of the View to be 48. Try using flex inside the text styling:
text: {
  color: '#FFF',
  textAlign: 'center',
  width: 48,
  flexDirection: 'row',
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center',
},


Thank you for the solution. I noticed that the image caused more problems when the values exceeded four or five digits. Ultimately, I removed the marker image and created a custom marker using React Native
